# Open Multiple Hyperlinks based on autofilter results in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink, runtime-error, autofilter, vba

Edit #1
I am trying to open multiple hyperlinks. All hyperlinks are for .pdf files. The hyperlinks are not sorted i.e. a cell preceding or succeeding a hyperlink might not be a hyperlink. I am using a autofilter based search. Out of let's say 100 visible rows form the autofilter, 60 of them have hyperlinks in a designated column. I would like to open all these files using Excel VBA.

I have been using

```
    Sub tobedeleted()

Dim Selrng As Range
Dim srch_cr As Variant

Set Selrng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

srch_cr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selrng)

    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each hl In srch_cr.Hyperlinks
        hl.Follow
    Next hl

    For Each hl In ActiveWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Hyperlinks
    Next hl
End Sub
```

I have not been able to open these Hyperlinks.

Also the Designated column uses the Excel function hyperlink and I am basically using a vlookup to get the file location from a dump in another sheet. The Hyperlink function in the column activates the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and see what errors your code is throwing.

Also, you say you are using AutoFilter to find the rows, but your code is running against `Selection`. AutoFilter doesn't automatically select the rows. You would need to use

```
For each hl in Worksheet().Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).hyperlinks
```

Based on the discussion in comments, I think there are several issues:

1. I'm not sure why you're using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`, as it doesn't seem to buy you anything. There's no telling what shape range your user might select, and reshaping it doesn't seem to me to be helpful.
2. Change your loop to `For each hl in selrng.hyperlinks`

   - you're currently trying to use *variant*.hyperlinks, when .hyperlinks is an object of *range*

If that doesn't help, I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Yes but i am using the autofilter part and opening hyperlinks in 2 different macros. The reason is for debugging and reviewing if the information is correct.The Hyperlink opening part is seperate. I also tried Edit 1 above

Comment: Just looked at your updated code, the new `For Each...` loop doesn't do anything - it just loops. You'll need some sort of code in there...  Step through, line-by-line, in debug, see how your variables are getting set. Make sure everything is ending up where you expect it to be. If not, and you can't figure it out, update your OP with the specifics, we might be able to help. From here, I'm just guessing, now.

Comment: On your OP (original post - the question you asked) below the tags, there is a link to `edit`. Edit your question, add the new stuff (if you leave the old stuff then the conversations make sense, and someone in the future may find your post, discover that their issue matches, and be able to use the solution). Add as much detail as possible to help us help you.

Comment: Ok so i removed the 'on error resume next' and i am getting an error saying object required at both for next loops

Comment: I Used you above recommendations, still not working. Anybody with fresh ideas? , help plz!!!